# Transition time is only applied if target value changes

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

> Note: I updated the question with a simpler example as I found that it is not an issue with `transform` in particular, but with how the transition timing is applied. You can still see the more complex example in the edit history.

Here is a simple example: when you mouse over the "Grow" button, the bar will grow to 400px in 5 seconds; and after exiting the "Grow" button, the bar will shrink automatically to 0px in 10 seconds. If you mouse over the "Shrink" button, the bar will shrink to 0px in 2 seconds.

Although it doesn't, it takes 10 seconds to go back to 0px even when mousing over "Shrink":

```css
#bar {
  width:0;
  border-left:1px solid gray;
  height: 40px;
  transition: width 10s;
  background: green;
}

#grow,#shrink {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: gray;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px black;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#grow:hover ~ #bar {
  width: 400px;
  transition: width 5s;
}

#shrink:hover ~ #bar {
  width: 0px;
  transition: width 2s;
}
```

```html
<span id="grow">Grow</span>
<span id="shrink">Shrink</span>

<div id="bar"></div>
```

At first I thought it could be a problem with specificity (even when `#shrink:hover ~ #bar` is more specific than just `#bar`), so I added an `!important` like this:

```
#shrink:hover ~ #bar {
  width: 0px;
  transition: width 2s !important;
}
```

Still it didn't work. After some try-error, I found that changing the value actually makes the browser take the new transition time, even if the change is insignificant. So, for example, this will work:

```css
#bar {
  width:0;
  border-left:1px solid gray;
  height: 40px;
  transition: width 10s;
  background: green;
}

#grow,#shrink {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: gray;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px black;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#grow:hover ~ #bar {
  width: 400px;
  transition: width 5s;
}

#shrink:hover ~ #bar {
  width: 0.000001px;
  transition: width 2s;
}
```

```html
<span id="grow">Grow</span>
<span id="shrink">Shrink</span>

<div id="bar"></div>
```

That works. Also, I noticed another case in which it works: when it goes directly from "Grow" to "Shrink" without transitioning to anything else (you may be able to see it by moving from "Grow" to "Shrink" really fast or by removing the margin so they are together).

I have been able to replicate this issue in Chrome, Internet Explorer/Edge, Firefox, and Safari. So I don't know if it's a real issue or me misunderstanding how this should work (quite possible too).

Why does this happen? Is there a way to apply the new transition time without having to change the target value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I picked up this from the specs., saying

> For each element with a before-change style and an after-change style,
>   and each property (other than shorthands) for which the before-change
>   style is **different** from the after-change style, implementations must
>   start transitions based on the relevant item

which I interpret being the case here, where your `#bar` *before-change* value is **not** different from the `#shrink:hover ~ #bar` *after-change* value, hence no transition starts.

Src: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#starting

Comment: I must say I find the wording in the specs is confusing, but this looks correct. So the whole issue was really an incorrect assumption on my side: it doesn't matter if we are half way through the transition, the actual value is already 0 so there's no change and no new transition triggered (because really there's not a value change).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro I am no expert on reading those specs. and find them also  often difficult to understand, though based on your 2 samples and what actually worked, that paragraph appear to match the given scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still digging but here are my conclusions.

First, this could just be a bug. That's always possible.

However, if we assume that it's functioning as it should, I think the real reason here are the "identical keyframes".

You see, it's not about the angle of `rotate()` function. It's about `transform` property being virtually identical for `#arm` and `#brake`. If I imagine `css` parsing your styles for animations and creating "keyframes", it might think that the first definition is the same as the second.

If we add a completely useless but unique function to one of those two declarations, then they are treated as two unique keyframes and behave as you want them to. That's what you were doing by decreasing the angle by one degree.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|VT323");

.round {
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#board {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
  border: 12px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 12px red;
}

#pointer {
  z-index: 1;
}

#knot {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 2;
}

#arm {
  width: 126px;
  height: 6px;
  background: red;
  transform: translate(-85%, -50%) rotate(-42deg);
  border-radius: 80% 6px 6px 80%;
  transform-origin: 85% 50%;
  transition: transform 14s;
}

#speed:hover~#board #pointer #arm {
  transform: translate(-85%, -50%) rotate(62deg);
  transition: transform 7s;
}

#brake:hover~#board #pointer #arm {
  transform: translate(-85%, -50%) rotate(-42deg) rotateX(0);/* I added this useless rotateX() */
  transition: transform 3s;
}

.bar {
  width: 300px;
  height: 2.30769px;
}

.bar:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
  height: 4.61538px;
}

.bar::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 12px;
  background: black;
}

.bar:nth-of-type(odd)::after {
  width: 15.78947px;
}

.bar:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-42deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-34deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-26deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-18deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-10deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(6) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-2deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(7) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(6deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(8) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(14deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(9) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(22deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(10) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(30deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(11) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(38deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(12) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(46deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(13) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(54deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(14) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(62deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(15) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(70deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(16) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(78deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(17) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(86deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(18) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(94deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(19) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(102deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(20) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(110deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(21) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(118deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(22) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(126deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(23) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(134deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(24) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(142deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(25) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(150deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(26) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(158deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(27) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(166deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(28) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(174deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(29) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(182deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(30) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(190deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(31) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(198deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(32) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(206deg);
}

.bar:nth-of-type(33) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(214deg);
}

.num {
  font-family: Oswald, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  position: absolute;
}

.num:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: 66.66667px;
  left: -75px;
}

.num:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 16.66667px;
  left: -96.77419px;
}

.num:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: -37.5px;
  left: -92.30769px;
}

.num:nth-of-type(4) {
  top: -78.94737px;
  left: -60px;
}

.num:nth-of-type(5) {
  top: -100px;
  left: -7.5px;
}

.num:nth-of-type(6) {
  top: -85.71429px;
  left: 42.85714px;
}

.num:nth-of-type(7) {
  top: -50px;
  left: 78.94737px;
}

.num:nth-of-type(8) {
  top: 3.75px;
  left: 93.75px;
}

.num:nth-of-type(9) {
  top: 51.72414px;
  left: 76.92308px;
}

#mileage {
  padding-top: 187.5px;
}

#box {
  width: 75px;
  height: 25px;
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  color: rgba(200, 255, 0, 0.8);
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 0.325em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: VT323, Oswald;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

#miles {
  float: left;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-left: 0.325em;
  font-family: Oswald, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

#red-bar {
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0;
  transform: translate(-101%, -61.7%) rotate(28deg);
}

#red-bar::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(86%, -22.5%) rotate(97deg);
}

#speed,
#brake {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-family: Oswald, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: gray;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(-300px, -50%);
}

#speed {
  transform: translate(200px, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="center" id="speed">Speed</div>
<div class="center" id="brake">Brake</div>
<div class="center round" id="board">
  <div class="center" id="red-bar"></div>
  <div class="center" id="pointer">
    <div class="center round" id="knot"></div>
    <div class="center" id="arm"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="center" id="bars">
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
    <div class="bar center"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="center" id="numbers">
    <div class="num center">0</div>
    <div class="num center">20</div>
    <div class="num center">40</div>
    <div class="num center">60</div>
    <div class="num center">80</div>
    <div class="num center">100</div>
    <div class="num center">120</div>
    <div class="num center">140</div>
    <div class="num center">160</div>
  </div>
  <div class="center" id="mileage">
    <div id="box">31415</div>
    <div id="miles">miles</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated the question to create a better [mcve], and the error still happens even for `width` (although your explanation would work for that too). I thought about it being a bug, but if all major browsers do it this way, the issue is probably with my code.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro yeah I'm really leaning towards "the way css parses for animation keyframes" but I'm not even sure how to check that against documentation and spec.